# How to print the longest sequence of numbers from int[] array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, sequence

I'm a beginner in programming and I need to print the longest sequence of numbers from int[] array. 
For example, if we have:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 0, 12, 2, 2, 2, 12, 0};
```

Result should be:

```
String result = "5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5";
```

I wrote some bad code that don't work, but maybe it will give you some ideas.

```
public String findLargestSequence(int[] numbers) {
        int bestStart = 0;
        int curStart = 0;
        int bestLength = 1;
        int curLength = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] > numbers[i - 1]) {
                curLength++;
                if (curLength > bestLength) {
                    bestStart = curStart;
                    bestLength = curLength;
                }
            } else {
                curStart = i;
                curLength = 1;
            }
        }
        List<String> identical = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < bestLength; i++) {
            identical.add(String.valueOf(numbers[bestStart + i]));
        }
        return Joiner.on(", ").join(identical);
    }
```

**Update.** 
Thanks to @phatfingers, I've found problem:
`(numbers[i] > numbers[i - 1])` should be `(numbers[i] == numbers[i - 1])`.
But still there is one another problem. 
If we have something like:

`int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4};`

The result of it is:

```
"3, 3"
```

I think in this case, we could:

1) say, that we don't have any one longest sequence OR

2) show all that sequences, like:

```
String result = "Founded sequences: " + sequence1 + ", " + sequence2;
```

3) do nothing with that code above.

What would you do?

Comment: For starters, your check for `(numbers[i] > numbers[i - 1])` should be `(numbers[i] == numbers[i - 1])`.

Comment: I don't have code, but here's my theory. First, sort the array from lowest to highest. Then, check for how many consecutive occurrences of each number there are. Then you can figure out the sequence off that.

Comment: Except for what @phatfingers pointed out, your code looks beautiful and correct to my eye. blackHorse, does it work with the suggested correction? If not, in what way not?

Comment: @MarkYisri, I suppose the numbers have to be consecutive in the input array. If this is correct, sorting the array is not only superfluous, it may also give a result that is too long.

Answer (score 0):

this show the max occurrence, you can also count it and print them

```
public static int consecutive(int[] array) {
        if (array.length <= 1) {
            return array.length;
        }    
        int maxRun = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            int thisRun = 1;
            while (i < array.length && array[i - 1] + 1 == array[i]) {
                thisRun++;
                i++;
            }
            if (maxRun < thisRun) { // checking geater occurance
                maxRun = thisRun;
            }
        }
        return maxRun;
    }
```

Comment: While the code looks correct, I think we’re helping the asker better by pointing in the direction of how to mend his or her own attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle 4 cases in the algorithm that you can divide in two parts:

**Setting the state of the current serie :**

- increment the current serie if it grows
- reinit the current serie when it changes

**Setting the state of the max serie :**

- increment the max serie if it grows
- reinit the max serie when it changes

In the actual code these conditions are not respected in the loop.

I commented two logic errors to illustrate the problem :

```
  if (numbers[i] > numbers[i - 1]) {
    // error : you don't increment the current serie when it grows
    // because the condition if true only if the the current value is 
    // superior to the previous one
    curLength++;
    if (curLength > bestLength) {
        bestStart = curStart;
        bestLength = curLength;
    }
  } 
   // error : you don't reinit the current serie only when it changes
   // because numbers[i] <= numbers[i - 1] is not true if the new number is   
   // superior to the previous one while it is a change
   else {     
    curStart = i;
    curLength = 1;
   }
 }
```

Here is the proposed code that handles the 4 conditions two by two:

```
public static String findLargestSequence(int[] numbers) {

    // variables to maintain the max serie found and the number associated
    int sizeMaxSerieFound = 0;
    int numberMaxFound = numbers[0];

    // variables to maintain the current serie found and the number
    // associated
    int sizeMaxCurrentSerie = 0;
    int numberCurrentSerie = numbers[0];

    boolean isMaxSerieIsTheCurrent = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        int currentNumber = numbers[i];

        // FIRST STEP : set the state of the current serie

        // increment the current serie if it grows or for the first
        // iteration
        if (currentNumber == numberCurrentSerie) {
            sizeMaxCurrentSerie++;
        }
        // else we reinit to 1 the current serie
        else {
            sizeMaxCurrentSerie = 1;
            numberCurrentSerie = currentNumber;
            isMaxSerieIsTheCurrent = false;
        }

        // SECOND STEP : set the state of the max serie

        // we increment the current number of the actual max serie
        if (currentNumber == numberMaxFound && isMaxSerieIsTheCurrent) {
            sizeMaxSerieFound++;
        }

        // we reinit the serie because we have found a new greater serie
        else if (currentNumber != numberMaxFound && sizeMaxCurrentSerie > sizeMaxSerieFound) {
            sizeMaxSerieFound = sizeMaxCurrentSerie;
            numberMaxFound = currentNumber;
            isMaxSerieIsTheCurrent = true;
        }

    }

    List<String> identical = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeMaxSerieFound; i++) {
        identical.add(String.valueOf(numberMaxFound));
    }
    return Joiner.on(", ").join(identical);
}
```

Comment: The comments on errors in the askers code are good. I think your own code is not correct either, though it’s not 100 % clear. Example input: `new int[] { 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5 }`. Expected output in my understanding: `5, 5, 5`. Observed output: `2, 2, 2, 2`.

Comment: @Ole V.V Indeed  when I increment the current number of the actual max serie it missed a `&&` condition in a `if` because we have to increment the max serie only if the current number is the same : `currentNumber == numberMaxFound` and the second condition and that we  also have to be in the max serie.  Otherwise we increment a serie that is not a serie as it has gaps between.